# Live SDK Skydrive access from Windows 7 WPF

Tags: wpf, onedrive

I am trying to develop an app that stores a user's file on Skydrive. I am trying to use the Live SDK  however there doesn't seem to be much on Live SDK for Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I currently have Live SDK installed via NuGet and I can access the classes etc from the .dll. The only problem is, I have no idea how to use it due to the lack of documentation. If anyone has a quick sample of how to at least sign in to Skydrive and/or access files from there it would be great! Even if someone can link me to an article detailing the above!

Please let me know if you need more info.

EDIT: CODE

```
Try
    Dim auth As New LiveAuthClient("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    Dim loginresult As LiveLoginResult = Await auth.IntializeAsync(New String(0) {"wl.skydrive"})
    MsgBox(loginresult.Status.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    If loginresult.Status = LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected Then
        MsgBox("Signed In", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error signing in: " + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there are currently no official Live SDK's for VB.net. If anyone does find an SDK let me know!

Answer (score 0):

First search on Google [SkyDrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx) and [SkyDrive Core Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826545.aspx).

Full examples are available through the first two links, [Folders and files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx).

For signing in, there's the Live SDK, [Signing users in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826543.aspx#csharp).

Comment: I've seen all of those websites, however, the code does not work (I convert it to VB.net WPF code). All the code examples appear to be for W7 Phone or Windows 8 App Store. I need code for Windows 7 WPF Desktop applications.

Comment: @Asryael: Then you need to let us know what problems you are facing. These are the available resources, if you say you have "problems using it", then there's no way for me to know what to answer, other than linking to tutorials and the official API. Why can't you work with the WPF desktop examples?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826543.aspx#csharp the above code is all that is needed for signing in to Windows Live. However it always returns Unknown as the loginresult.Status.